# Deserializing json data from jquery post method directly to string array

Tags: asp.net, json, deserialization, jquery-post

Is there a way to deserialize an array sent by jquery post method to directly c# string array(string[])?

I tried posting data like this

```
$.post(url,
          {
           'selectedTeams[]'=['Team1','Team2']
          },
          function(response) {}, 'json');
```

And trying to consume it like this in C# class

```
string jsonData = new StreamReader(context.Request.InputStream).ReadToEnd();
var selectedTeams = new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<string[]>(jsonData);
```

It didn't work and ofcource it should not as there is no property selectedTeams[] in string[]

I am aware of the way to define a class something like this

```
class Teams
{
   public string[] SelectedTeams{get;set;}    
}
```

and then do the deserialization.

But I think that is an unnecessary defining a class so isn't there a way to directly convert json array to c# string array

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Figure it out!

Using stringified array object rather than direct named json parameter to pass as data solved my problem

I am now posting like this

```
var Ids = new Array();
Ids.push("Team1");
Ids.push("Team2");

$.post(url, JSON.stringify(Ids), function(response) {}, 'json');
```

And now able to deserialize json response directly to string array like this

```
string jsonData = new StreamReader(context.Request.InputStream).ReadToEnd();
var selectedTeams = new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<string[]>(jsonData);
```

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

you could develop your own class, but I would suggest you use this:
http://json.codeplex.com/